# what am I doing wrong RxJS operators

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I am learning Angular and RxJS operator. I am working with Hearthstone API to training it. What am i doing wrong ? I wanna filter stream to return only "Shaman" cards. I know, Api gives me opportunity to get cards by class but i wanna only trainig RxJS so i am considering this problem. My ts component :

```html
cards: Card[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cardsService.getCards().pipe(
      filter((el: any) => el.playerClass === 'Shaman')
    ).subscribe(res =>
      this.cards = res);
  }
```

And here my service:

```html
export class CardsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getCards(): Observable<Card[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('X-RapidAPI-Key', '78976c5326mshb1a81046ad68d52p11b362jsn35ec089dd9db');
    return this.http.get<Card[]>('https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.rapidapi.com/cards/sets/Basic', { headers });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your observable stream return type is an array, then the items in the stream are arrays. the filter pipe operator will filter items in the stream. Your problem comes from putting the any type on the filter input - remove and it should be types as card[]. You then try to pull a property off an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCards` method is returning `Observable<Card[]>`, so that means it returns an Observable that emits an array of Cards. In this case, your Observable will emit one value and then complete.

The `filter` Observable operator differs from the `filter` method on the `Array` prototype. The Observable `filter` will filter *emissions* from the source `Observable` and not actually change the data in each emission. You're explicitly typing `(el: any)` in your `filter` method; this should never be done in a delegate method and should instead be implicitly typed as `Card` from the Observable itself. That's why your `filter` method wouldn't compile originally.

Since we don't want to filter out *what* is emitted, but instead want to change the *value* of each emission, we'd use `map` instead:

```
this.cardsService.getCards().pipe(
  map(el => el.filter(s => s.playerClass === 'Shaman'))
).subscribe( // ...
```

This instead changes the value of the emission (by using `Array.prototype.filter` on the emitted array).